# Longitude and latitude are not being displayed

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to display the users' position using GPS. I have written the following code so that if GPS is disabled on the device, then the user should enable it by going to the settings.If it is enabled then it should show the current position of the user. I am running the application on a android device. I don't get any errors when running the application but the position will not be displayed. Please help
    ------------Main Activity--------------------

```
package com.android.disasterAlertApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener ll = new mylocationlistener();
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);

if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is Enabled in your devide", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  else{
    showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
   }
  }

  private void showGPSDisabledAlertToUser(){
  AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
  alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("GPS is disabled.Do you want to enable it?")
 .setCancelable(false)
 .setPositiveButton("Goto Settings Page To Enable GPS",
 new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
 Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(
 android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
 startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
    }
  });
 alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
 new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
 dialog.cancel();
  }
 });
 AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
 alert.show();
 }

  private class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      if (location != null) {
   Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLatitude() + "");
Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLongitude() + "");
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
    location.getLatitude() + "" + location.getLongitude(),
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
   }

   public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
  }
   public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
  }
   public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
  }
  }
 } 

 ------------Manifest-----------------

 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<activity
    android:name=".Splash"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

       <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.disasterAlertApp.MAINACTIVITY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>

 </application>   
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES"></uses-permission>
 </manifest>
```

Comment: added the internet permission, still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

For getting GPS positions it takes time and if your inside a building its difficult to get gps values, if the device is in outside of a bulding we can get gps values..

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your device GPS hardware is working. I had 2 brand new LG Lucid phones and the GPS did not work on either of them. On the location settings check only the GPS box and then start Google Map to see if it can obtain location.